# npm install -g typescript gives Z_DATA_ERROR

Tags: npm

Running

```
npm install -g typescript
```

Is giving me error:

```
npm ERR! code Z_DATA_ERROR
npm ERR! errno -3
npm ERR! zlib: incorrect data check

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/REDACTED/.npm/_logs/2022-10-14T00_07_52_514Z-debug.log
(base) Webbs-MBP:~ REDACTED$
```

Not sure what this error means or why it's happening.

I'm able to install other packages globally, `npm install -g ts-node` works fine.

Looking at the log file I see:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   '/Users/REDACTED/.nvm/versions/node/v14.19.0/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/Users/REDACTED/.nvm/versions/node/v14.19.0/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   '-g',
1 verbose cli   'typescript'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.16
3 info using node@v14.19.0
4 verbose npm-session f9097623d247d337
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readGlobalPackageData
7 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/typescript 326ms (from cache)
8 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for typescript@latest zlib: incorrect data check
9 timing stage:rollbackFailedOptional Completed in 13ms
10 timing stage:runTopLevelLifecycles Completed in 658ms
11 verbose stack ZlibError: zlib: incorrect data check
11 verbose stack     at Unzip.write (/Users/REDACTED/.nvm/versions/node/v14.19.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/minizlib/index.js:147:22)
11 verbose stack     at Object.write (/Users/REDACTED/.nvm/versions/node/v14.19.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/tar/lib/parse.js:313:19)
11 verbose stack     at PassThrough.ondata (internal/streams/readable.js:731:22)
11 verbose stack     at PassThrough.emit (events.js:400:28)
11 verbose stack     at addChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:293:12)
11 verbose stack     at readableAddChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:267:9)
11 verbose stack     at PassThrough.Readable.push (internal/streams/readable.js:206:10)
11 verbose stack     at PassThrough.Transform.push (internal/streams/transform.js:166:32)
11 verbose stack     at PassThrough.afterTransform (internal/streams/transform.js:101:10)
11 verbose stack     at PassThrough._transform (internal/streams/passthrough.js:46:3)
11 verbose stack     at PassThrough.Transform._read (internal/streams/transform.js:205:10)
11 verbose stack     at PassThrough.Transform._write (internal/streams/transform.js:193:12)
11 verbose stack     at writeOrBuffer (internal/streams/writable.js:358:12)
11 verbose stack     at PassThrough.Writable.write (internal/streams/writable.js:303:10)
11 verbose stack     at PassThrough.ondata (internal/streams/readable.js:731:22)
11 verbose stack     at PassThrough.emit (events.js:400:28)
12 verbose cwd /Users/REDACTED
13 verbose Darwin 20.6.0
14 verbose argv "/Users/REDACTED/.nvm/versions/node/v14.19.0/bin/node" "/Users/REDACTED/.nvm/versions/node/v14.19.0/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "typescript"
15 verbose node v14.19.0
16 verbose npm  v6.14.16
17 error code Z_DATA_ERROR
18 error errno -3
19 error zlib: incorrect data check
20 verbose exit [ -3, true ]
```

OS: macOSBigSur with M1 Chip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's apparently a bug in the most recent version of node, see [Zlib error when attempting to run npm install or yarn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69452504/zlib-error-when-attempting-to-run-npm-install-or-yarn)

make sure you have node version manager (nvm) installed, then downgrade to node 14.17:ts

```
nvm install 14.17
nvm alias default 14.17

npm install typescript --save-dev
tsc
```

worked for me after experiencing the same error :)