# node npm error code Z_DATA_ERROR errno -3 zlib: incorrect data check

Tags: node.js, typescript

i'm trying to run my typescript project using `tsc`
but i get this error:

```
Found 181 errors in 4 files.

Errors  Files
     1  node_modules/@types/eslint-scope/node_modules/@types/eslint/helpers.d.ts:1
     1  node_modules/@types/eslint/helpers.d.ts:1
   176  node_modules/@types/react-dom/node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts:3089
     3  node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts:2970
```

I tried updating one of the modules like this but it didnt work:

```
npm install --save @types/eslint-scope
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: project@1.4.0
npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"18.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"16.13.1" from @design-systems/theme@3.7.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@design-systems/theme
npm ERR!   peer @design-systems/theme@"^3.0.0" from @appfabric/providers@2.2.46
npm ERR!   node_modules/@appfabric/providers
npm ERR!     @appfabric/providers@"2.2.46" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! /Users/abell5/.npm/_logs/2023-06-23T21_41_25_807Z-eresolve-report.txt
```

nor did this work:

```
% npm i npm@latest
...
npm ERR! code Z_DATA_ERROR
npm ERR! errno -3
npm ERR! zlib: incorrect data check
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's apparently a bug in the most recent version of node, see [Zlib error when attempting to run npm install or yarn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69452504/zlib-error-when-attempting-to-run-npm-install-or-yarn)

you need do downgrade yarn and reinstall typescript

make sure you have node version manager (nvm) installed, then downgrade to node 14.17

```
nvm install 14.17
nvm alias default 14.17

npm install typescript --save-dev
tsc
```

worked for me after experiencing a similar error :)

then, ensure your JS project builds successfully, and only edit the tsconfig.json file as in https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/migrating-from-javascript.html and then run tsc. should work.